# Could not find aapt with appium server

Tags: android, testing, adb, emulation, appium

I am currently trying to run a test on an android emulator device with appium,
everything goes fine, appium unlocks the screen of the device but then I have this error:

```
[ADB] Error: Could not find aapt Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the Android SDK root directory path
```

I set the **ANDROID_HOME** varaibale im my bash file to :

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/tar/android/android-sdk-linux/
```

and I also set the other variables to :

```
export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/home/tar/android/android-sdk-linux

export PATH=${PATH}:/home/tar/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools

export PATH=${PATH}:/home/tar/android/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

But I am still facing the same error,

does someone have an idea how to solve this please?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure that you've got the SDK installed correctly and that your path in ANDROID_HOME points to the folder containing the /bin folder.

Then try running:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

or log-in and log-out to apply the new changes in the bash file.

You could also reuse your ANDROID_HOME variable:

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
```

This way you don't have to change all the variables if the location of the SDK changes.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows:

1. Open My Computer Properties
2. Click on 'Advanced System Setting'
3. Click on 'Environment Variables..'
4. Create Variable for **User** and **System** both
5. Restart the IDE.!

Please look the image below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`sudo nano ~/bash_profile` and add:

`export ANDROID_HOME=/home/tar/android/android-sdk-linux/`

`export ANDROID_SDK_HOME=/home/tar/android/android-sdk-linux`

`export PATH=${PATH}:/home/tar/android/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools`

`export PATH=${PATH}:/home/tar/android/android-sdk-linux/tools`

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of Android Studio SDK, `aapt` is not in tools nor in platform-tools but in build-tools. You need to add it to your PATH for Appium to find it.

```
export PATH="$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy aapt.exe from build-tools to platflorm-tools. Also make sure to add ANDRIOD_HOME to sdk folder in Windows Environment variables. This solved my problem.