# How to set ANDROID_HOME environment variable in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, appium

I am facing this error while running the java mobile automation test case with appium

```
mvn -Dtest=SavedPhotosTest  test -DFILEPATH="sample.apk"
```

> An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
>   Original error: packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Original
>   error: Could not find aapt Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment
>   variable with the Android SDK root directory path. (WARNING: The
>   server did not provide any stacktrace information)

I've set the ANDROID_HOME in my .bashrc already

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
```

appium is also running on the another terminal

Configurations:

> IntelliJ IDE --> ideaIC-2017.2.4 Android-studio -->
>   android-studio-ide-162.4069837-linux appium --> 1.7.1

I've already tried the following links:

https://discuss.appium.io/t/error-could-not-find-aapt/671/5
[Could not find aapt with appium server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433718/could-not-find-aapt-with-appium-server)

https://discuss.appium.io/t/error-could-not-find-aapt/671

[How to set IntelliJ IDEA Project SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16765726/how-to-set-intellij-idea-project-sdk)

Comment: Try command `find -name aapt` in your `$ANDROID_HOME` and you'll find it's in `build-tools/<version>/`.

Comment: Hey @LymZoy It's return like this  ./build-tools/26.0.2/aapt. What to do with this?

Comment: Append `/26.0.2` to `$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools` in your `$PATH` variable.

Comment: Already tried that. It's not working. appium-settings app opened and closed suddenly. then the ANDROID_HOME error thrown.

Comment: Sorry, I only know how to solve your `$ANDROID_HOME` problem. I have no experience with appium.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same issue. Appium was not able to locate ANDROID_HOME env variable.
In my case reason behind this issue was I was running appium with **sudo** access on my linux machine. If you are running with root privilege, try running without it.

Answer (score -1):

Source it.

`source .bashrc`

If you did, try reopening every terminal and android studio.