# Not able to run automation script of python(mac)

Tags: python, python-3.x, appium, appium-android, python-appium

I am using https://github.com/appium/python-client framework to run automation.

I am getting below error while running scripts.

> Exception: Message: An unknown server-side error occurred while
>   processing the command. Original error:
>   packageAndLaunchActivityFromManifest failed. Original error: Could not
>   find aapt Please set the ANDROID_HOME environment variable with the
>   Android SDK root directory path.

Also, I set ANDROID_HOME environment variables on mac.

Can somebody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is not related to library you are using. Please run `appium-doctor` in terminal and see the output. It should be something like this

```
    info AppiumDoctor Appium Doctor v.1.4.3
    info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic starting ###
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Node.js binary was found at: /usr/local/bin/node
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Node version is 6.11.0
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode is installed at: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Xcode Command Line Tools are installed.
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ DevToolsSecurity is enabled.
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ The Authorization DB is set up properly.
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Carthage was found at: /usr/local/bin/carthage
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ HOME is set to: /Users/poornima
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ ANDROID_HOME is set to: /Users/poornima/Library/Android/sdk
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ JAVA_HOME is set to: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ adb exists at: /Users/poornima/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ android exists at: /Users/poornima/Library/Android/sdk/tools/android
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ emulator exists at: /Users/poornima/Library/Android/sdk/tools/emulator
    info AppiumDoctor  ✔ Bin directory of $JAVA_HOME is set
    info AppiumDoctor ### Diagnostic completed, no fix needed. ###
    info AppiumDoctor 
    info AppiumDoctor Everything looks good, bye!
    info AppiumDoctor
```

**If Not**

Make sure your tools and platform tools are also added to path variable in bash profile.

1. Open bash profile `open ~/.bash_profile`
2. Add tools and platform tools

   ```
   export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/poornima/Library/Android/sdk
   export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
   export PATH=$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$PATH
   ```

Refer this link: [Could not find aapt with appium server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37433718/could-not-find-aapt-with-appium-server)